# Probability over a period of time

Tags: probability, self-study

If there is a 

0.3% chance of living through 2017,

0.2% chance of living through 2018,

0.15% chance of living through 2019,

0.05% chance of living through 2020, and

0% chance of living through 2021.

Is the Probability of being dead in 2019 equal to:

0.3*0.2*0.85

= 0.051

Is the probabilty of being dead in 2021 equal to:

0.3*0.2*0.15*0.05*1

= 0.00045

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll treat this as [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) and provide hints. Please take a look at the tag's wiki and consider adding the tag to your question. If this is helpful or you are still stuck, you can write a comment.

You are not calculating the probability of *being dead* in a particular year. You are calculating the probability of *dying* in a particular year. The difference is that you can *be dead* in 2019 by dying in 2019, but also by dying in 2017 and 2018. See the difference?

This should give you an idea of how to calculate the probability of being dead in a particular year.

Sanity check: if you are dead in 2019, then you are in particular dead in 2021 (barring a rising from the dead in the meantime), so the probability of being dead in 2021 should be at least as large as the one of being dead in 2019. It isn't in your calculation.

Comment: Would,
P(dead in 2019) = 0.7+0.3*0.8+0.3*0.2*0.85 = 0.991
And,
P(dead in 2021) = 0.991 + 0.3*0.2*0.15*0.95 + 0.3*0.2*0.15*0.05*1 = 1

Comment: Exactly! Of course, you can get the probability of 1 for 2021 more easily by noting that you will die in 2021 in any case, regardless of whether you made it this far.